# matplotlib remove whitespace between plot and y axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I remove the whitespace here?

[image]

Many thanks!

Comment: The duplicate  I used isn't exact but I think it makes it obvious what you should use (i.e. `axis('tight')`).

Comment: I've added another question that does it selectively for x or y.